# Reflection much slower than normal

Tags: java, reflection, jvm, weblogic, weblogic11g

I am currently working on a Java project in which I am trying to learn the ins and outs. In previous projects, I have used Java reflection in order to create a toString() by calling each getter in an object and parsing it to display the value. This method has been a helpful, clean, and dynamic way to display the data.

Below is a heavily simplified version of my code:

```
private static String objectToString(Object o) {
    LOGGER.debug("entering ObjectStringUtils::objectToString()");


    ....

    Class<?> oClass = o.getClass();
    String className = oClass.getName();
    Method[] methods = oClass.getMethods();

    for (Method m : methods) {
         if ([method is a getter]) {
               String methodName;
               Object value;
               try {
                   methodName= m.getName();
                   LOGGER.debug("Invoking " + className + "::" + methodName);
                   Object value = m.invoke(o);
                   LOGGER.debug("Invoked " + className + "::" + methodName);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   value = null;
               }

               LOGGER.debug(methodName+ " -> " + value);
         }
    }
}
```

This produces logger output which looks like this:

```
14:47:49,478 [] DEBUG ObjectStringUtils:? - Invoking org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl::isOpen
14:47:49,613 [] DEBUG ObjectStringUtils:? - Invoked org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl::isOpen
14:47:49,613 [] DEBUG ObjectStringUtils:? - isOpen -> true
```

Notice that it took Java **139 milliseconds** to call the function. **It takes this long to perform the reflection in any method in any class, even if the method is only a standard getter which performs no logic other than to return a value.** This means that it takes far too long to perform the operation when there are multiple nested values involved. When I used reflection previously on WebSphere 7, it took a tiny fraction of this long to perform the  operation.

So my question is: **why** is it taking so long to process? I understand that reflection is slower, but it shouldn't be on the magnitude of 140 milliseconds to call a getter. Is this an artifact of the way it takes WebLogic a long time to call a function, or the fact that line numbers appear to be stripped from the .class files? So far, I don't have any idea.

Comment: You should rename `variableName` to `methodName` for clarity.

Comment: Have you tried profiling it?

Answer (score 1):

When you benchmark a piece of code, you must time the same operation *several times*, otherwise the test is meaningless - it could have been caused by garbage collection or by another process running on the same computer.

Comment: I have run the piece of code several hundred times over, and it takes several minutes. This has caused the code to be unrunnable when iterating over a few hundred classes.

Answer (score 0):

When `Method`s are cached - e.g. used in a framework and `oClass.getMethods()` is called only once, reflective call to a method is only ~2-3 slower than a direct method call. I think that `oClass.getMethods()` must be the slowest part in your reflection, not the method invocation.

So may be it's `SessionImpl::isOpen` which is slow by itself? I.e. it checks if it's still connected, or does any slow interaction with the database? 139 ms is very slow even for a DB transaction, so this also could happen because of some errors occuring during this call.